# PHP Script to check all databse entries only reads one row then stops

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an automated script that will check once a day if an account has their due date 'today' and if so, add interest rates on their current loan, but for some reason my script stops once it scans the first entry and does not go through all the entries in the database.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thank you in advance!
(or suggest if there's a better way to do this altogether)

```
<?php
require('include/dbconfig.php');

$host     = "redacted";
$user     = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$datbase  = "lending";
$tbl_name = "users";
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($datbase);

$sql_query  = "SELECT user_id, datedue, locurrentamt, interestrate, first_name FROM $tbl_name";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql_query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_set)) {
    $user_id    = $row['0'];
    $first_name = $row['4'];
    // FOR EACH DATABASE ENTRY CHECK THE DUE DATE
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
    $datetoday     = date("Y/m/d");
    $dateduefromdb = $row['1'];
    // RETURN FALSE IF THE DATES ARE BOGUS
    if (!$a = strtotime($datetoday))
        return FALSE;
    if (!$z = strtotime($dateduefromdb))
        return FALSE;
    // MAN PAGE http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php
    $a_jd          = GregorianToJD(date('m', $a), date('d', $a), date('Y', $a));
    $z_jd          = GregorianToJD(date('m', $z), date('d', $z), date('Y', $z));
    $countdowndate = $z_jd - $a_jd;

    if ($countdowndate == 0 && $countdowndate >= 0) {

        $dueamt         = $row['2'];
        $dueinterest    = $row['3'];
        $interestcharge = $dueamt * $dueinterest;
        $finalinterest  = $interestcharge + $dueamt;
        $first_name     = $row['4'];

        $sql_query = "UPDATE users SET locurrentamt='$finalinterest' WHERE id='$user_id'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some error?and please dont use mysql_*

Comment: There is no error, the script runs fine but it only returns one row and stops for some reason. 

I'll look up on mysqli  in the mean time thanks!

Comment: One obvious issue that can cause the loop (script) to end early is the 'date checks'. e.g: `if (!$a = strtotime($datetoday)) ...`. These should generate log errors as a minimum or throw exceptions? Please don't catch the exceptions. Also set `error_reporting` to E_ALL would be useful if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide info about what is in your database?

Currently, if `datedue` is evaluated as null, or anything invalid, the following code will cause the function to return with value FALSE (preventing processing of further rows).

```
   if (!$z = strtotime($dateduefromdb))
        return FALSE;
```

You may want something like

```
   if (!$z = strtotime($dateduefromdb))
        continue;
```

As this will simply skip over the rest of the loop iteration, and start the next iteration, which would process the next db row.

Comment: Hello! To answer your question, the datedue variable is a date field. Thank you for the tip! I will add it to the code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out my problem. It's a rough solution but I made a for loop after counting the amount of entries in the database. If anyone is interested, here's the finished script for your reference. Have a great day!

```
<?php
require('include/dbconfig.php');

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);
$numrowsadjust = ++$num_rows;

for ($x = $num_rows; $x <= $numrowsadjust; $x++){
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$x' LIMIT 1";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
  {
  //$user_id=$row['0'];
  //$first_name = $row['1']; Display stuff for debugging
  date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
  $alpha=date("Y/m/d");
  $omega=$row['20'];
    // RETURN FALSE IF THE DATES ARE BOGUS
        if (!$a = strtotime($alpha)) continue;
        if (!$z = strtotime($omega)) continue;
  // MAN PAGE http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php
        $a_jd = GregorianToJD( date('m', $a), date('d', $a), date('Y', $a) );
        $z_jd = GregorianToJD( date('m', $z), date('d', $z), date('Y', $z) );
    $countdowndate = $z_jd - $a_jd;

      if ($countdowndate == 0 && $countdowndate >= 0){

      $dueamt = $row['76'];
      $dueinterest = $row['82'];
      $interestactual = ($dueinterest / 100);
      $interestcharge = $dueamt * $interestactual;
      $finalinterest = $interestcharge + $dueamt;
      $first_name = $row['1'];

      $addthis = "UPDATE users SET locurrentamt='$finalinterest' WHERE user_id='$x'";
      mysql_query($addthis);
      }
  }
  die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```